# TypeError: expected a character buffer object using .translate

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, unicode, translate

I'm getting the error:

> TypeError: expected a character buffer object

In the line where it says `words=user_input_txt.translate(translate_table).lower().split()`.  I checked the type for the argument `user_input_txt` and its Type Unicode.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and don't quite understand previous postings.  If someone could advise on how to fix I would greatly appreciate!

```
def contains_bad_words(user_input_txt):
    """ remove punctuation from text 
        and make it case-insensitive"""
    translate_table = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)
    words = user_input_txt.translate(translate_table).lower().split()
    for bad_word in blacklist:
        for word in words:
            if word == bad_word:
                return True
    return False
```

EDIT:  I've revised my solution per the recommendation received from Daniel.  However, I'm now getting the error:

> TypeError: maketrans() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given).

Could someone please advise what I'm doing wrong?  I read that `string.maketrans` could take one argument as long as it's a dict.  But `translate_table` is a dictionary no?  Please help!!

```
def contains_bad_words(user_input_txt):
    """ remove punctuation from text 
        and make it case-insensitive"""
    translate_table = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)
    translate_table_new = string.maketrans(translate_table)
    words = user_input_txt.translate(translate_table_new).lower().split()
    for bad_word in blacklist:
        for word in words:
            if word == bad_word:
                return True
    return False
```

SECOND EDIT:
So i fixed the problem by converting the unicode string to a string, and changing the number of arguments to maketrans.  However, I'm still very puzzled why my solution above doesn't work.  I read somewhere that it can take 1 argument provided it must be a dictionary, which is clearly what I did.  Could someone help explain why the above doesn't work but the below does:

```
def contains_bad_words(user_input_txt):
    """ remove punctuation from text
        and make it case-insensitive"""
    user_typ = user_input_txt.encode()
    translate_table_new = maketrans(string.punctuation, 32*" ")
    words = user_typ.translate(translate_table_new).lower().split()
    for bad_word in blacklist:
        for word in words:
            if word == bad_word:
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: Your  second example is mixing the translate types.  Unicode strings use a translation dictionary, and not `string.maketrans`.  `string.maketrans` prepares a 256-byte translation string for the byte string version of `translate`.   See my answer.

Comment: What is the string type of your input?  It really matters here.  Python 2 makes things confusing by allowing you to call `.encode` on a byte string even if it was already a byte string, so your 3rd example may not need the `.encode`.  Try `print type(user_input_text)` and give us the result.  Better yet, make a standalone example that has sample input, is indented properly, and shows expected vs. actual output.  See the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: hi Mark!  thanks so much for the help and detailed response.  I can confirm that when I do print type(user_input_text) the type is Unicode.  To clarify, when i do python manage.py runserver on the very first code above, it runs fine.  It's when I run the tests does this error come up.  I haven't started doing any testing on this particular function yet, so am very puzzled why this error is showing up.  Since my input is unicode, would you agree that the logic in the first code above is correct?

Comment: Yes, if your input is a `unicode` string, your first function works.  If your input is `str`, then it gives `TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object`.  So your tests must be passing `str` not `unicode`.  The stack trace from the `TypeError` exception should help you track down the test.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That makes sense.  The field that's being tested is a charField in the model, that's why all the test cases pass in a string.  In your opinion, would you recommend that I use the third version above then since my tests are passing in `str` and not `unicode`? Sorry for the newbie question, this is my first time learning Django and python in general

Comment: If it is plain ASCII text byte strings and you want to delete punctuation, then the last part of my answer (`.translate(None,string.punctuation)`) is what I'd recommend.  If you want to replace the punctuation with spaces, then use your 3rd attempt less the `.encode`.  That converts Unicode to byte strings, and isn't needed if you already have byte strings.  If your text is not only ASCII, then you probably want to `.decode` the text to Unicode and use your first version.

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't complete examples.  It matters what your input is.

There are two versions of `translate` in Python 2: `str.translate` and `unicode.translate`.  Here's the help on both:

```
>>> help(str.translate)
Help on method_descriptor:

translate(...)
    S.translate(table [,deletechars]) -> string

    Return a copy of the string S, where all characters occurring
    in the optional argument deletechars are removed, and the
    remaining characters have been mapped through the given
    translation table, which must be a string of length 256 or None.
    If the table argument is None, no translation is applied and
    the operation simply removes the characters in deletechars.

>>> help(unicode.translate)
Help on method_descriptor:

translate(...)
    S.translate(table) -> unicode

    Return a copy of the string S, where all characters have been mapped
    through the given translation table, which must be a mapping of
    Unicode ordinals to Unicode ordinals, Unicode strings or None.
    Unmapped characters are left untouched. Characters mapped to None
    are deleted.
```

If you have a byte string (`str`), then the table translate requires must be a byte string of length 256 or None.  An optional 2nd argument to `.translate` deletes characters.

`string.maketrans` can generate the 256-byte string.  It takes two arguments that must be the same length.  Here's the help:

```
>>> import string
>>> help(string.maketrans)
Help on built-in function maketrans in module strop:

maketrans(...)
    maketrans(frm, to) -> string

    Return a translation table (a string of 256 bytes long)
    suitable for use in string.translate.  The strings frm and to
    must be of the same length.
```

Demo (`a`->`1`, `b`->`2`, `c`->`3`, delete `d`, `e`, and `f`):

```
>>> import string
>>> test = 'abcdefg'  # byte string in Python 2
>>> test.translate(string.maketrans('abc','123'),'def')
'123g'
```

The `unicode` version takes a dictionary of Unicode ordinals to Unicode ordinals, Unicode strings, or None.

Demo (change `a`->`b`, `c`->`xxx`, and delete `d`):

```
>>> test = u'abcdefg' # Unicode string in Python 2
>>> xlat = {ord('a'):ord('b'),ord('c'):u'xxx',ord('d'):None}
>>> test.translate(xlat)
u'bbxxxefg'
```

So for your examples, you want to delete punctuation.  Depending on if you have a byte string or a Unicode string, choose one of the following:

```
>>> import string
>>> translate_table = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)
>>> u'abcd.,def'.translate(translate_table)
u'abcddef'

>>> import string
>>> 'abcd.,def'.translate(None,string.punctuation)
'abcddef'
```

Answer (score 0):

`.translate` does not take a dict directly. You need to run it through `str.maketrans` first.

```
translate_table = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)
translate_table = str.maketrans(translate_table)
words = user_input_txt.translate(translate_table).lower().split()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for responding!  It looks like b/c I'm using python 2.7, I can't use str.maketrans.  So I tried string.maketrans(translate_table) and it's telling me maketrans takes exactly two arguments not one.  Could you advise???